# What constitutes rude?

Tags: discussion

I flagged a comment as rude. It was declined by the moderator and I am OK with that. I am not complaining about moderators. They do fine job and give freely of their time.

But I would like to weigh in on if you think the comment was rude

> go to space, without a suit, and enjoy the buffet

To me that is go suffer a freezing death with no oxygen.  I looked it up for slang and don't find it as a slang term.

The question is [Flavour components in beer](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/4791/flavour-components-in-beer/4792#4792)

Again I am OK - no real harm.  I sold my space craft last year. It was getting difficult to get approval for even low orbit space flight with heightened security. So no chance of unprotected space walks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm the one who handled that flag.  Here is the full comment for context:

> I don't believe that chemicals in food products necessarily mean additives that are unnatural. There are lots of chemicals responsible for flavor and aroma of hops. When I add baking powder to my biscuits, that's also a chemical (actually, a few). Like I say, if you want chemical free food, go to space, without a suit, and enjoy the buffet.

In hindsight, yes, the part that you've pointed out could certainly be considered rude, and I should have accepted the flag rather than declining it. When I was initially reviewing it, though I read it several times, in its entirety I didn't see what was rude or offensive about it, given that the bulk of it was on point for the conversation. Since I didn't know at that time that it was only the final sentence at issue, I didn't think to separate it from context, and to be honest, was probably reading a bit to quickly at that point to notice that the tone changed.   I'll watch that in the future.